Why is the tty2 showing login screen with no response in EndeavourOS KDE Plasma?
I'm on EndeavourOS with KDE plasma (recently installed, left everything default). I opened Virtual Terminal by Ctrl+Alt+F3 and exit by Ctrl+Alt+F2. But, Login screen of plasma has opened which is not responding. But later I got to know that KDE plasma actually uses tty1 so I came back by Ctrl+Alt+F1 and continued my work.
Why tty2 is being used by KDE plasma when it's actually running on tty1? Why is tty2 is not responding to inputs? Or am I missing something?
I've used Arch Linux previously, which KDE plasma is on tty2. But here it's on tty1 and messing with tty2.
Is this the same for every EndeavourOS with Plasma. Can someone please explain
